# Removing object mapping many to many relation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In ASP.NET MVC I have three tables: 
`Users`, `Roles`, `UsersInRoles` (standard many to many joining table).
When I've mapped it to EF, it created two Entity Types: `Users` and `Roles`.
Now I want to delete some user using code like below:

```
var aspnetUsers = _db.aspnet_Users.Single(a => a.UserId == id);
_db.aspnet_Users.DeleteObject(aspnetUsers);
```

of course I can't do it, because in SQL level in table `UsersInRoles` there is a connected row.

How to delete that row from EF level (`UsersInRoles` table is not mapped)?

Comment: you could also use `cascade on delete` option (form Fluent) to set up your tables like that, if that's the behavior you want at all times (though I personally don't like it, however depends on your model/wishes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove all the roles from the user object before calling `SaveChanges()` on the context:

```
var aspnetUser = _db.aspnet_Users.Single(a => a.UserId == id);

foreach(var role in aspnetUser.Roles.ToArray())
{
    aspnetUser.Roles.Remove(role);
}

_db.aspnet_Users.DeleteObject(aspnetUser);

_db.SaveChanges();
```

This will prevent the exception caused by the referential constraints in the database and ensure that the corresponding records in UsersInRoles table get deleted.